# azure - list containers in python

Tags: python, azure, sdk, containers

I'm trying to list the containers under an azure account using the python sdk - why do I get the following?

```
>>> azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.BaseBlobService(account_name='x', account_key='x').list_containers()
>>> <azure.storage.models.ListGenerator at 0x7f7cf935fa58>
```

Surely the above is a call to the function and not a reference to the function itself.

Comment: you get the following according to [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py#L470) it return `return ListGenerator(resp, self._list_containers, (), kwargs)`

Comment: you can access what you want `containers = blob_service.list_containers() >>>for c in containers:
    print(c.name)`

Comment: thank you very much - `c.name` is especially helpful

Comment: you are welcome accept the answer if it was correct

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you get the following according to [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/54e60c8c029f41d2573233a70021c4abf77ce67c/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py#L609) it return `ListGenerator(resp, self._list_containers, (), kwargs)`

you can access what you want as follow:

python2:

```
>>> from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService 
>>> blob_service = BaseBlobService(account_name='x', account_key='x')
>>> containers = blob_service.list_containers() 
>>> for c in containers: 
      print c.name
```

python3

```
>>> from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService 
>>> blob_service = BaseBlobService(account_name='x', account_key='x')
>>> containers = blob_service.list_containers() 
>>> for c in containers: 
      print(c.name)
```

Comment: This works for me. In case you meet the error of "cannot import name 'BlockBlobService'", please refer to this link https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/issues/389. I use "pip install azure-storage-blob==2.1.0" and "from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService". It solved the bug.

Answer (score 6):

for python 3 and more recent distribution of `azure` libraries, you can do:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=account_name, account_key=account_key) 
containers = block_blob_service.list_containers()
for c in containers: 
   print(c.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to **[source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/54e60c8c029f41d2573233a70021c4abf77ce67c/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py#L573)**

You can access the containers in the storage account by using the snippet below:

```
from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService

blob_service = BaseBlobService(account_name='<your account name>', account_key='<your account key>')
containers = blob_service.list_containers() 
for container in containers: 
    print ("Container name: {}".format(container.name))
```

more info on setting up account name and account key visit [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#copy-your-credentials-from-the-azure-portal)